# Браузер не показывает вывод сервера

Tags: c, сервер, http, tcp, localhost

Есть простой tcp сервер на си, всё, что но делает, это выводит для пользователя список файлов из директории откуда он запущен функцией send().
Вопрос: как получить этот вывод через браузер, т.к. при попытке localhost:8080, пишет "сайт localhost дал недействительный ответ", при подключении через telnet всё работает.

Comment: а вы http заголовки отправляете? Про cgi вообще слышали?

Comment: Нет, если можно, объясните пожалуйста

Comment: @ArchDemon, `cgi` тут ни к месту (а вот с `http` очевидно в точку)

Answer (score 0):

*"Есть простой tcp сервер на си, всё, что но делает, это выводит для пользователя список файлов из директории откуда он запущен функцией send()."*

*"Вопрос: как получить этот вывод через браузер, т.к. при попытке localhost:8080, пишет "сайт localhost дал недействительный ответ", при подключении через telnet всё работает."*

**Все верно.** Вы ведь понимаете что браузер получает не тупо набор текста, он получает данные по http протоколу. Этот протокол проще некуда, в нем первые строчки описание протокола, дальше (user-agent, cookie, и трр) http заголовки.

**И только потом идет сам html.**

Пример:

```
HTTP/1.x 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://yandex.com/about.html#contacts
Date: Thu, 19 Feb 2009 11:08:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Content-Length: 110
(пустая строка)
<html><body><a href="http://yandex.com/about.html#contacts">Click here</a></body></html>
```

В этом примере показано что браузер получает по **TCP**.

Подробное описание http протокола https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP